# An elliptic operator whose corresponding symbol Hamiltonian vector field has an isolated periodic orbit

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-operators, periodic-orbit

Let $D$  be a  differential operator  on the  space of  smooth functions  on  a  manifold $M$.  The   symbol of  $D$  can  be  [considered  as  a  Hamiltonian on the  cotangent bundle  $T^*M$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296000/what-does-the-flow-of-the-principal-symbol-of-the-differential-operator-tell-us). We  call  this  Hamiltonian  as  "Corresponding  symbol Hamiltonian"

Motivated by the above  interesting  linked  question and  [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210996/an-algebraics-hamiltonian-vector-field-with-a-finite-number-of-periodic-orbits2) and  [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155590/an-algebraic-hamiltonian-vector-field-with-a-finite-number-of-periodic-orbits1?noredirect=1&lq=1)  we  ask the  following  question:

> Is there  an elliptic  operator  on a  manifold whose corresponding  symbol Hamiltonian  has an isolated   periodic  orbit?

Note: We  add the  ellipticity condition  since  we  learn from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155590/an-algebraic-hamiltonian-vector-field-with-a-finite-number-of-periodic-orbits1/156288#156288) that for  differential operator associated with  a  vector  field, which is  a  non elliptic operator, we do not have  an isolated periodic orbit

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you want an isolated periodic orbit on some fixed energy level.  Pick your favorite Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ such that there is an isolated closed geodesic.  Then, the geodesic flow on the unit tangent bundle has a corresponding isolated period orbit.

The Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_{g}$ is elliptic and has principal symbol

$\sigma(\Delta_{g})(\xi)=\lVert \xi \rVert_{g}^{2}.$

as a function on $T^{*}M.$  The Hamiltonian flow of $\sigma(\Delta_{g})$ is the geodesic flow of $g,$ and therefore the previous comments apply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention to my question. I am really sory for not replying earlier. By isolated  i mean globally isolated not restricted to a level. But I realy appreciate your interesting approach using isolated closed geodesic.  BTW how can one define (and gurante its existence) an ISOLATED  closed geodesic?My previos +1 to your kindly attention and your answer!